# Error when running ntpd on openVZ host: cap_set_proc() failed to drop root privileges:

Tags: centos, ntpd, ntp

CentOS 6.x | OpenVZ

I want to run a NTP server on a vps host of mine. Is this possible?

When I try to start ntpd, it fails immediately and gives the following error:

```
Mar 14 22:47:44 ev1 ntpd[3456]: cap_set_proc() failed to drop root privileges: Operation not permitted
```

I've localized it to a setting in /etc/sysconfig/ntpd

```
# Drop root to id 'ntp:ntp' by default.
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"
```

When this line is enabled, it fails (presumably because the shared kernel refuses to allow the privileges change). If I comment it out, ntpd runs fine but runs as root which is A Bad Thing.

Is there anyway to get ntpd to run as the ntp user on openVZ?  Admittedly I know it's a great idea to have this running on a OpenVZ server but I'd still like to try.

Answer (score 6):

You should add the [Capability option](http://openvz.org/Man/vzctl.8#Capability_option) "`sys_time`" as stated in [[Users] How does the clock work in OpenVZ?](http://lists.openvz.org/pipermail/users/2007-March/000646.html) via the command:

```
vzctl set 101 --capability sys_time:on --save
```

You should of course replace "101" by the CTID of your container.

Then reboot the machine/container. Now, `ntpd` should run as expected with the "`ntp`" user.

You can then check that the `ntpd` server works with:

```
/etc/init.d/ntpd status
```

And:

```
ntpq -c as
ntpq -c pe
```